# Concatenate multiple files in a directory in an ordered fashion, allowing NAs

Tags: awk, sed

I have 6 multiple files, each having only 1 column containing names. I want to read all these files and combine them in 1 file so that it looks like this:

```
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5  file6  Count
adam   adam   adam   adam   adam   adam   1
Roy    NA     Roy    Roy    NA     NA     0.5
NA     Sam    Sam    NA     NA     NA     0.33
```

This shows that name `adam` was there in every file while `Roy` was in 3 files (file1,3,4) and `Sam` in 2 files (file2,3). Last column is additional and computed after combining all files. It gives me a ratio of a name appearing in all files. e.g for Roy it was observed in 3 out of 6 files hence `Count` is `3/6 = 0.5`

The `colnames` of resulting dataframe should represent the actual file names. Let's say that the file I read were named `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and so on..

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: good task, show your actual efforts

Comment: Avoid `sed` when counting and division are involved. I'd take `python`, but `perl` or `awk` will work as well.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest combing all into one is done by: `paste * > mergedFile.txt` but I am not getting a solution around how to order them in the fashion I want, that if name is not there then a blank or NA should be introduced.

Answer (score 0):

For the given input, it seems every file has the same number of lines and extension, you simply could pipe to column.

```
$ paste *.txt | column -t
```

**EDIT:**

If the NA's are "emtpy cells" use this:

```
$ paste *.txt |  column -s $'\t'  -tn
```

This works also if the files have different line numbers.

Comment: Number of lines in different files are different. For example, file1 has has only two names (adam and Roy) while file3 has three names (adma, Roy and Sam). NA's should be ideally introduced, that is my desired output format. When I do paste, I get un-ordered binding of all files.

Comment: You misunderstood it. NA's are not there in initial files. I want to insert them if a file doesn't contain the corresponding name. So that every line is ordered and aligned at the end. If that name appear in file, write it, otherwise insert NA in its place.

Comment: I thought that's what I wrote. And how is the output of the edited command?

Comment: Thats how header looks like: `A1BG-AS1             A2M-AS1                A2M-AS1              A1BG-AS1             A1BG,
A2M-AS1              AAAS                   A2ML1                AAAS                 A1BG-AS1,
A2ML1                AACS                   AACS                 AACS                 A2M-AS1,
AACS                 AADAT                  AADACL3              AADAT                AAAS,
AADACL3              AAED1                  AADAT                AAED1                AACS,
`

Comment: Instead of having only one `A1BG` value and rest 4 `NA` in the first row, that's what I am getting. In above example I am combining 5 files. For the sake of readability, I am ending every row with `,` originally it is a `\n` but in the comments I don't know how I can show it as a table.

Comment: This is how I want it: `1 2 3 4 5 Count,
NA NA NA NA A1BG 0.2,
A1BG-AS1 NA NA A1BG-AS1 A1BG-AS1 0.6,
A2M-AS1 A2M-AS1 A2M-AS1 NA A2M-AS1 0.8,
A2ML1 NA A2ML1 NA NA 0.4,
NA AAAS NA AAAS AAAS 0.6,`

Comment: Please, could you post your last three comments in your OP. Than we have readable in/output.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Python script which read every file and create dictionary containing name as key and number of counted names as value. At the end you can divide every value by number of files.

Someting like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  

filelist= ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt']
dictionary= dict()

for file in filelist:
    fd= open(file, "r")

    for name in fd.readlines():
        name= name.strip()
        if name in dictionary.keys():
            dictionary[name]+= 1
        else:
            dictionary[name]= 1
        fd.close()

for x in dictionary.keys():
    print("{0} : {1}".format(x, float(dictionary[x])/len(filelist)))
```

**EDIT:**
Python is by default in Linux. You can copy it, paste to file and execute. It's working

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and suggestion. If I have to go for other languages, then I already have a solution by using R but the problem is I want a linux based solution because previously all processing of the files is done in linux.

Comment: @Newbie check edited code. I check, and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried your solution and it is working but as said earlier I can also do it in R. For me explicitly mentioning the file names is not optimal in this case. I was looking for some one-liner like I mentioned in my comments.